# Twemoji doesn't render on options dropdown

Tags: javascript, html, twemoji

I am using twemoji to display emojis and I found it working well, but when using the options tag, it renders the default emojis instead of twemoji.

Here's an example code

```html
<script src="https://twemoji.maxcdn.com/v/latest/twemoji.min.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<body>
  <div style="display:grid; grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;">
    <div>
      <p></p>
      <select>
        <option value="love"></option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <div>
      <p></p>
      <select>
        <option value="cool"></option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <div>
      <p></p>
      <select>
        <option value="sob"></option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
<script>
  twemoji.parse(document.body);
</script>
```

The emojis displayed on top are what I expect to see, and below is the unintended result.
[image]

How can I make it so that it renders the twemoji emojis instead?

I looked up on Google and StackOverflow to see if this problem happened to anyone else, but wasn't able to find a similar question.

Answer (score 0):

The HTML Element option don't supports images, [only text](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/option#technical_summary), and yes, in a way [emojis are text](https://unicode.org/emoji/techindex.html).

For POC (Proof of concept):

```js
twemoji.parse(document.body);
twemoji.parse(document.querySelector("select option[value='love']"));
twemoji.parse(document.querySelector("select option[value='cool']"));
twemoji.parse(document.querySelector("select option[value='sob']"));
```

```html
<script src="https://twemoji.maxcdn.com/v/latest/twemoji.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <div style="display:grid; grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;">
    <div>
      <p></p>
      <select>
        <option value="love"></option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <div>
      <p></p>
      <select>
        <option value="cool"></option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <div>
      <p></p>
      <select>
        <option value="sob"></option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

But you can try without the `option`, for example with [Dropdowns](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/components/dropdowns/) from `Bootstrap`.